# Conditionally rendering Text view with a large string causes performance issue

Tags: performance, swiftui, swiftui-text

My SwiftUI app has a network log screen that shows network requests sent and recorded by the app. There is a button to toggle the visibility of each request. Requests are serialized and stored as strings, so they can be displayed on this screen.

Some of the response objects are very large — as response objects tend to be sometimes — which is causing a 1-2 second delay when the “toggle visibility” button is pressed. Is there a way to optimize the performance of the Text view that renders the content?

```
struct NetworkLogsScreen: View {
    var logs: [NetworkLogEntry]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(logs.indices.reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                    LogItem(logItem: logs[index])
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Network Requests")
    }
}

struct LogItem: View {
    var logItem: NetworkLogEntry

    @State var isExpanded: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(logItem.timestamp.formatted())
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("toggle visibility")
                }
            }
            if self.isExpanded {
                Text(logItem.responseBody)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does removing `reversed()` from `logs.indices.reversed()` significantly improve the  performance?

Comment: @Norman - it does not. The performance difference can be observed when toggling visibility of a very large response vs a small one. The small one renders just fine.

Comment: You can try truncating the text, only showing the first 50 characters, and after expanding, showing the rest. How long is the text?

Comment: I read some where "You need fixed heights on your elements. Will take care of the performance issues", perhaps wrapping responseBody in it's own ScrollView.

Comment: @Jalil - it's quite long... a huge blob of text created from an API response.

Comment: @Norman - I think having a fixed height would solve this. In that regard, perhaps this is a design issue than a code issue. I think I will truncate the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix:

Ended up using a substring of the actual content. This fixed the issue. So you can no longer see the entire content. I added a button that copies the entire response to your clipboard and this satisfied my needs. The UIPasteboard functionality hangs sometimes, but I supposed that's what you get for copying 1500+ lines of text.

I did see some improvement from using a `.frame` modifier setting the maxHeight and adding a `truncationMode` to that, but it did not completely fix the issue.

So the modified code is basically...

```
if self.isExpanded {
    Text(logItem.responseBody.prefix(2000))
}
```

Would love to figure out if there's a way to fix the issue without modifying the user-facing options.

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` is not a for loop it shouldn't be used with indices and the `id: \.self` is a mistake. Furthermore the `logs[index]` inside `ForEach`'s content closure can actually cause a crash with an index out of range exception. You need to fix it to be like:

```
ForEach(logs.reversed()) { logItem in
    LogItem(logItem: logItem)
}
```

You can achieve this by making `NetworkLogEntry` conform to `Identifiable` or specify an `id` param that is a unique property of the model struct not the struct itself because that is not unique across mutations of the logs array.

You could also fix your date formatting:

```
Text(logItem.timestamp format: .date)
```

Replace `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack` with `List`.

Change `var` to `let`.

Remove the `if isExpanded` and change the `Text` to:

```
Text(isExpanded ? logItem.responseBody : "")
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback @malhal. I believe you are right, I will make those changes. However, I do not think those aspects of the code are causing the described performance issue.

Comment: ok i added a few other fixes.

Comment: all good feedback, although it doesn't address the described performance issue.

Comment: ok i added one more

Comment: `Text(isExpanded ? logItem.responseBody : "")` does not improve the issue